# How can we develop weak classifier/learner in C# for IRIS/any dataset?

Tags: machine-learning, statistics

I want to develop weak classifier/learner in C# for any dataset, Can anyone guide me how can we make classifier?

Answer (score 2):

There is no classifier which will have the characteristic beeing a *weak-classifier* for *any* dataset! I'm assuming here, that we are talking about the weak-classifier characteristic common in [boosting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boosting_(machine_learning)).

Beeing a weak-classifier means, that it's better as random-guessing. Now let's just assume your data consists of pure *noise*. There is no way to predict something better than random-guessing.

This won't answer your question but should show you that you should work on the basics first (before asking a way to general question)!

Comment: there is IRIS dataset in statistical learning so I've been given assignment to make weak classifier of any feature from IRIS dataset so I can't understand how to do it. Can you please guide me?

Comment: @salif I know the iris-set. But your question is way to broad. Start by using the classic approaches like LogisticRegression and SVM's. But i really can't understand the motivation/environment behind your task.

Comment: actually I've been given an assignment to develop any weak classifier using one feature of IRIS data-set but I can't understand how to do it, can you please explain? Thanks

Comment: you make me understood any weak classifier by example in coding

Comment: @saif Now it sounds like homework and it's still very broad as you are showing no own work. Check [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Statistical_classification) and chose of the simple linear classifiers.

Comment: yeah it's my homework, I'm student but searched a lot about weak classifier but cannot find solution to my problem

Comment: Start by understanding what a weak-classifier is. Then you will understand, why a simple linear-classifier does what you want. And there are infinite resources available on the internet about linear classifiers. *Invest something!*